# how to resize a drawable image inside an EditText

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an edit text with a background image,

I want to add a drawable in the center of the edit text.

```
 <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/etReceipt"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                            android:clickable="true" 
                            android:drawableStart="@drawable/Draw _Image"
                            android:background="@drawable/bgImage"/>
```

is ther a possibility to resize the drawable to fit with the edit text?

is it possible to put it in the center?

Answer (score 0):

Create center.xml in res/drawable folder and add this code

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/bgImage"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

In your edit text add:

```
android:background="@drawable/center"
```

Hope this helps, happy coding!

Comment: I tried this in an `EditText` which is placed inside an `ActionBar`. But it didn't work.